# Is there any package for currency of Countries dropdown select in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, select, dropdown, currency

I'm doing a Order Management in angular 9. I want to find a package which can be imported to get a drop down of currencies around the world. For example, USD, INR etc.

Comment: Check this json https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/2973986

Comment: thanks, this will do, but i've already figured it out, please check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've standardized the code for angular.

### create a model

```
export interface DropDownList {
    code: any
    text: any
}
```

### in component.ts file add the following

```
import { DropDownList } from 'src/app/shared/models/util.model';

CurrencyList: DropDownList[] = [
{code:"AFN",text:"Afghanistan Afghanis – AFN"},
{code:"ALL",text:"Albania Leke – ALL"},
{code:"DZD",text:"Algeria Dinars – DZD"},
{code:"ARS",text:"Argentina Pesos – ARS"},
{code:"AUD",text:"Australia Dollars – AUD"},
{code:"ATS",text:"Austria Schillings – ATS"},
{code:"BSD",text:"Bahamas Dollars – BSD"},
{code:"BHD",text:"Bahrain Dinars – BHD"},
{code:"BDT",text:"Bangladesh Taka – BDT"},
{code:"BBD",text:"Barbados Dollars – BBD"},
{code:"BEF",text:"Belgium Francs – BEF"},
{code:"BMD",text:"Bermuda Dollars – BMD"},
{code:"BRL",text:"Brazil Reais – BRL"},
{code:"BGN",text:"Bulgaria Leva – BGN"},
{code:"CAD",text:"Canada Dollars – CAD"},
{code:"XOF",text:"CFA BCEAO Francs – XOF"},
{code:"XAF",text:"CFA BEAC Francs – XAF"},
{code:"CLP",text:"Chile Pesos – CLP"},
{code:"CNY",text:"China Yuan Renminbi – CNY"},
{code:"COP",text:"Colombia Pesos – COP"},
{code:"XPF",text:"CFP Francs – XPF"},
{code:"CRC",text:"Costa Rica Colones – CRC"},
{code:"HRK",text:"Croatia Kuna – HRK"},
{code:"CYP",text:"Cyprus Pounds – CYP"},
{code:"CZK",text:"Czech Republic Koruny – CZK"},
{code:"DKK",text:"Denmark Kroner – DKK"},
{code:"DEM",text:"Deutsche (Germany) Marks – DEM"},
{code:"DOP",text:"Dominican Republic Pesos – DOP"},
{code:"NLG",text:"Dutch (Netherlands) Guilders - NLG"},
{code:"XCD",text:"Eastern Caribbean Dollars – XCD"},
{code:"EGP",text:"Egypt Pounds – EGP"},
{code:"EEK",text:"Estonia Krooni – EEK"},
{code:"EUR",text:"Euro – EUR"},
{code:"FJD",text:"Fiji Dollars – FJD"},
{code:"FIM",text:"Finland Markkaa – FIM"},
{code:"FRF",text:"France Francs – FRF"},
{code:"DEM",text:"Germany Deutsche Marks – DEM"},
{code:"XAU",text:"Gold Ounces – XAU"},
{code:"GRD",text:"Greece Drachmae – GRD"},
{code:"GTQ",text:"Guatemalan Quetzal – GTQ"},
{code:"NLG",text:"Holland (Netherlands) Guilders – NLG"},
{code:"HKD",text:"Hong Kong Dollars – HKD"},
{code:"HUF",text:"Hungary Forint – HUF"},
{code:"ISK",text:"Iceland Kronur – ISK"},
{code:"XDR",text:"IMF Special Drawing Right – XDR"},
{code:"INR",text:"India Rupees – INR"},
{code:"IDR",text:"Indonesia Rupiahs – IDR"},
{code:"IRR",text:"Iran Rials – IRR"},
{code:"IQD",text:"Iraq Dinars – IQD"},
{code:"IEP",text:"Ireland Pounds – IEP"},
{code:"ILS",text:"Israel New Shekels – ILS"},
{code:"ITL",text:"Italy Lire – ITL"},
{code:"JMD",text:"Jamaica Dollars – JMD"},
{code:"JPY",text:"Japan Yen – JPY"},
{code:"JOD",text:"Jordan Dinars – JOD"},
{code:"KES",text:"Kenya Shillings – KES"},
{code:"KRW",text:"Korea (South) Won – KRW"},
{code:"KWD",text:"Kuwait Dinars – KWD"},
{code:"LBP",text:"Lebanon Pounds – LBP"},
{code:"LUF",text:"Luxembourg Francs – LUF"},
{code:"MYR",text:"Malaysia Ringgits – MYR"},
{code:"MTL",text:"Malta Liri – MTL"},
{code:"MUR",text:"Mauritius Rupees – MUR"},
{code:"MXN",text:"Mexico Pesos – MXN"},
{code:"MAD",text:"Morocco Dirhams – MAD"},
{code:"NLG",text:"Netherlands Guilders – NLG"},
{code:"NZD",text:"New Zealand Dollars – NZD"},
{code:"NOK",text:"Norway Kroner – NOK"},
{code:"OMR",text:"Oman Rials – OMR"},
{code:"PKR",text:"Pakistan Rupees – PKR"},
{code:"XPD",text:"Palladium Ounces – XPD"},
{code:"PEN",text:"Peru Nuevos Soles – PEN"},
{code:"PHP",text:"Philippines Pesos – PHP"},
{code:"XPT",text:"Platinum Ounces – XPT"},
{code:"PLN",text:"Poland Zlotych – PLN"},
{code:"PTE",text:"Portugal Escudos – PTE"},
{code:"QAR",text:"Qatar Riyals – QAR"},
{code:"RON",text:"Romania New Lei – RON"},
{code:"ROL",text:"Romania Lei – ROL"},
{code:"RUB",text:"Russia Rubles – RUB"},
{code:"SAR",text:"Saudi Arabia Riyals – SAR"},
{code:"XAG",text:"Silver Ounces – XAG"},
{code:"SGD",text:"Singapore Dollars – SGD"},
{code:"SKK",text:"Slovakia Koruny – SKK"},
{code:"SIT",text:"Slovenia Tolars – SIT"},
{code:"ZAR",text:"South Africa Rand – ZAR"},
{code:"KRW",text:"South Korea Won – KRW"},
{code:"ESP",text:"Spain Pesetas – ESP"},
{code:"XDR",text:"Special Drawing Rights (IMF) – XDR"},
{code:"LKR",text:"Sri Lanka Rupees – LKR"},
{code:"SDD",text:"Sudan Dinars – SDD"},
{code:"SEK",text:"Sweden Kronor – SEK"},
{code:"CHF",text:"Switzerland Francs – CHF"},
{code:"TWD",text:"Taiwan New Dollars – TWD"},
{code:"THB",text:"Thailand Baht – THB"},
{code:"TTD",text:"Trinidad and Tobago Dollars – TTD"},
{code:"TND",text:"Tunisia Dinars – TND"},
{code:"TRY",text:"Turkey New Lira – TRY"},
{code:"AED",text:"United Arab Emirates Dirhams – AED"},
{code:"GBP",text:"United Kingdom Pounds – GBP"},
{code:"USD",text:"United States Dollars – USD"},
{code:"VEB",text:"Venezuela Bolivares – VEB"},
{code:"VND",text:"Vietnam Dong – VND"},
{code:"ZMK",text:"Zambia Kwacha – ZMK"},
```

]

### in component.html

```
<select name="orderCurrency" id="orderCurrency" formControlName="orderCurrency" class="form-control">
                        <option value="{{currency.code}}" *ngFor="let currency of CurrencyList">{{currency.text}}</option>
  </select>
```

this will help you create a basic currency dropdown